# how create a sql membership tables in my custom database in visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2012, membership-provider

I used to create website projects in vs2010 and create a simple SQL MEMBERSHIP SCHEMA into another database hosting server, like GoDaddy. My database schema tables looks like this.

```
aspnet_Applications
aspnet_Membership
aspnet_Paths
aspnet_PersonalizationAl lUsers
aspnet_PersonalizationPeruser
aspnet_Profile
aspnet_Roles
aspnet_SchemaVersions
aspnet_Users
aspnet_Usersl nRoles
aspnet_Web Event_Events
```

But now Im Trying the new VS2012. The default Project creates a local database with the fallowings tables:

```
Applications
Memberships
Profiles
Roles
Users
UserslnRoles
```

, this is totally diferent from the schema that i used to see. there is no `aspnet_` prefix and the tables are diferent... i cannot just rename the tables.

The `aspnet_regsql` tool creates the old version. with the `aspnet_` prefix..

How can I create this new schema in Visual studio 2012??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok after somre researsh this is a solution..

in vs2012, when using asp.net framework 4.5, there i no need to create this tables. You just put the correct connectrions string on web.config file and name it as "DefaultConnection".

When your register form tries to create a new user account, it verifies if the tables exists and create all the tables by it self.

That is it , simple as it goes.

Comment: This link explains a little bit. http://dotnetnsqlcorner.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/membership-in-aspnet-mvc-4.html

Comment: Does not have to be using asp.net framework 4.5 works in 4 aswell.